# SOAP and HTTP response codes

Tags: web-services, soap

Is SOAP end-point over HTTP expected to return any status code except 200 and 500? I have a SOAP end-point that has some business logic to reject requests when there are too many of them. I wonder what is the correct HTTP response code in this case - 500 or 429? The [SOAP specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383529) seems vague to me:

> SOAP HTTP follows the semantics of the HTTP Status codes for
>   communicating status information in HTTP. For example, a 2xx status
>   code indicates that the client's request including the SOAP component
>   was successfully received, understood, and accepted etc.
>
> In case of a SOAP error while processing the request, the SOAP HTTP
>   server MUST issue an HTTP 500 "Internal Server Error" response and
>   include a SOAP message in the response containing a SOAP Fault element
>   (see section 4.4) indicating the SOAP processing error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short SOAP uses HTTP/HTTPS as a transport. It is not bound to HTTP/S. SOAP can also use SMTP and JMS as a transport. Yes you can do SOAP via email.

The 200 and 500 error codes mentioned is just the standard way of letting SOAP know that the message contains a successful or failed SOAP request.  Thus I would use 500 with the error logged in the standard SOAP fault.

Comment: Yeah, I would agree with you. The only thing that prevents me from being 100% sure is that phrase "SOAP HTTP follows the semantics of the HTTP Status codes". Let's wait for any other opinions and arguments.

Comment: If I am not mistaken this changed in SOAP 1.2 where all 4xx and 5xx HTTP Status codes are considered an error: https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part2-20070427/#httpuse

Comment: Yeah 400/500 would make sense. Have not used SOAP since 2017... That just sounds horrible.... So things might have changed