# Changing the HTTP response code returned for a C# WSE 3 SOAP Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

My team inherited a very large and very old ASP.NET application using WSE 3.0 that provides a SOAP web service via the original .asmx Web Services.

While it's replacement is currently being built, my team is looking at improving monitoring & alerting (via New Relic).

Our issue is the number of 500 errors returned for failed authentication or when a request fails XSD validation.  This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51977328/2933177) leads me to conclude that it's working as designed/originally required.  But that the SOAP 1.2 specs allow for any 4xx / 5xx error to be returned.

Thus the question, is there any way to override the HTTP status code being returned by default in the .NET 4.8 framework with WSE 3.0 and an .asmx ASP.NET service?

I can see the following line of code in `SoapServerProtocol`

```
HttpStatusCode statusCode = helper.SetResponseErrorCode(base.Response, ex);
```

But I've not been able to find out anything about `SoapServerProtocolHelper`, `Soap12ServerProtocolHelper` or `Soap11ServerProtocolHelper`

**Update**
Of course, after posting the question I [found this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Services/System/Web/Services/Protocols/SoapServerProtocol.cs,907)

```
internal HttpStatusCode SetResponseErrorCode(HttpResponse response, SoapException soapException) {
        if (soapException.SubCode != null && soapException.SubCode.Code == Soap12FaultCodes.UnsupportedMediaTypeFaultCode) {
            response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType;
            soapException.ClearSubCode();
        }
        else if (SoapException.IsClientFaultCode(soapException.Code)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetHttpResponseStatusCode(response,
                (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
 
            for (Exception inner = soapException; inner != null; inner = inner.InnerException) {
                if (inner is XmlException) {
                    response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetHttpResponseStatusCode(response,
                (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
        response.StatusDescription = HttpWorkerRequest.GetStatusDescription(response.StatusCode);
        return (HttpStatusCode)response.StatusCode;
    }
```

So it would appear that my answer is no.  But I'll wait to see if anybody else can point out something I'm missing.